# Background Mode vs Turned Off Mode

Tags: java, android, webrtc

I made a video chat app on android. When I'm in the middle of a video chat, and I move the app to background mode, the video chat pauses. When I move it back to foreground mode, the video chat resumes. This is the desired behavior. However, when I'm in the middle of a video chat, and I press the power button to turn off the screen, the video chat continues. I want turning off the screen to behave just like background mode. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you share your code where you pause the video.? Are you pause video in onStop() ?

Comment: I don't have to do anything. It pauses itself when I move the app to background mode.

Comment: which library are you using? there must be some method to pause or resume .

Comment: I'm using WebRTC for the video chat. I was just wondering why the video chat pauses by itself in background mode, but that doesn't happen when the screen is turned off.

Answer (score 1):

You can pause the video chat when the app goes in onPause().
i.e add your video chat pause logic in the overridden onPause().

Comment: Yeah that's what I was going to do as a last resort. I actually don't use any code to pause the video when moving the app to background mode. Somehow it pauses itself.

Comment: Are you using a library for the video chat feature?

Comment: I'm using WebRTC for the video chat.

Answer (score 1):

Try following code with your default videoview

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onPause called");
    super.onPause();
    stopPosition = videoView.getCurrentPosition(); //stopPosition is an int
    videoView.pause();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.d(TAG, "onResume called");
    videoView.seekTo(stopPosition);
    videoView.start(); //Or use resume() if it doesn't work. I'm not sure
}
```

Comment: Yeah that's what my l plan on doing if there are no alternatives. I just don't understand why the video chat automatically pauses when I move it to background mode, but the video chat continues when I turn off the screen by pressing the power button.